# Add Maker at current location via Button in Mapbox on iOS

Tags: ios, dictionary, annotations, location, mapbox

I am trying to build an app where I can add a marker to the map by pressing a button. I could already achieve that by pressing the button the current location and a default title are written into an array as type **MGLPointAnnotation**. But I struggle with the **visualization** of the new annotation. I always get the error

`Type of expression is ambiguous without more context`

Here is my code so far:

```
func makeEntry(){
        guard let locValue: CLLocationCoordinate2D = locationManager.location?.coordinate else { return }

        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

        let point = Annotation()
        point.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: (locValue.latitude), longitude: (locValue.longitude))
        point.title = "Entry"
        pointAnnotations.append(point)
        mapView.addAnnotations(pointAnnotations) <-- triggers the error waring
        }
```

I am a complete newbie with Swift and hope that you can help me.

Edit:

Here is the rest of the core functions of the app:

```
func addButton(){
        entryButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: (view.frame.width/2)-100 , y: (view.frame.height)-75, width: 200, height: 50))
        entryButton.setTitle("Neuer Eintrag", for: .normal)
        entryButton.setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 100/255, green: 180/255, blue: 40/255, alpha: 1), for: .normal)
        entryButton.backgroundColor=(UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 255/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1))
        entryButton.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        entryButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(entryButtonWasPressed(_sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(entryButton)
    }
    @objc func entryButtonWasPressed(_sender: UIButton){
        makeEntry()
        print(pointAnnotations)   
    }
```

Edit edit: Here is the full code:

```
import UIKit
import Mapbox

class ViewController: UIViewController, MGLMapViewDelegate {
    let point = MGLPointAnnotation()
    var entryButton: UIButton!
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var annotation = MGLPointAnnotation()
    var pointAnnotations = [MGLPointAnnotation]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let mapView = MGLMapView(frame: view.bounds)
        mapView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        mapView.delegate = self

        // Enable heading tracking mode so that the arrow will appear.
        mapView.userTrackingMode = .followWithHeading

        // Enable the permanent heading indicator, which will appear when the tracking mode is not `.followWithHeading`.
        mapView.showsUserHeadingIndicator = true
        view.addSubview(mapView)

        // Set the map view's delegate
        mapView.delegate = self

        // Allow the map view to display the user's location
        mapView.showsUserLocation = true

        addButton()
        }

    func addButton(){
        entryButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: (view.frame.width/2)-100 , y: (view.frame.height)-75, width: 200, height: 50))
        entryButton.setTitle("New Entry", for: .normal)
        entryButton.setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 100/255, green: 180/255, blue: 40/255, alpha: 1), for: .normal)
        entryButton.backgroundColor=(UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 255/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1))
        entryButton.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        entryButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(entryButtonWasPressed(_sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(entryButton)
    }


    @objc func entryButtonWasPressed(_sender: UIButton){
        makeEntry()
        print(pointAnnotations)
    }


    func makeEntry(){
        guard let locValue: CLLocationCoordinate2D = locationManager.location?.coordinate else { return }

        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

        let point = MGLPointAnnotation()
        point.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: (locValue.latitude), longitude: (locValue.longitude))
        point.title = "Entry"
        pointAnnotations.append(point)
//        mapView.addAnnotations(pointAnnotations)
    }

        func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, annotationCanShowCallout annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> Bool {
        // Always allow callouts to popup when annotations are tapped.
        return true
        }

        func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, didSelect annotation: MGLAnnotation) {
        let camera = MGLMapCamera(lookingAtCenter: annotation.coordinate, fromDistance: 4500, pitch: 15, heading: 0)
        mapView.fly(to: camera, withDuration: 2,
        peakAltitude: 3000, completionHandler: nil)
        }
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, viewFor annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> MGLAnnotationView? {
        // Substitute our custom view for the user location annotation. This custom view is defined below.
        if annotation is MGLUserLocation && mapView.userLocation != nil {
            return CustomUserLocationAnnotationView()
        }
        return nil
    }

    // Optional: tap the user location annotation to toggle heading tracking mode.
    func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, didSelect annotation: MGLAnnotation) {
        if mapView.userTrackingMode != .followWithHeading {
            mapView.userTrackingMode = .followWithHeading
        } else {
            mapView.resetNorth()
        }

        // We're borrowing this method as a gesture recognizer, so reset selection state.
        mapView.deselectAnnotation(annotation, animated: false)
    }


// Create a subclass of MGLUserLocationAnnotationView.
class CustomUserLocationAnnotationView: MGLUserLocationAnnotationView {
    let size: CGFloat = 48
    var dot: CALayer!
    var arrow: CAShapeLayer!

    // -update is a method inherited from MGLUserLocationAnnotationView. It updates the appearance of the user location annotation when needed. This can be called many times a second, so be careful to keep it lightweight.
    override func update() {
        if frame.isNull {
            frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size, height: size)
            return setNeedsLayout()
        }

        // Check whether we have the user’s location yet.
        if CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid(userLocation!.coordinate) {
            setupLayers()
            updateHeading()
        }
    }

    private func updateHeading() {
        // Show the heading arrow, if the heading of the user is available.
        if let heading = userLocation!.heading?.trueHeading {
            arrow.isHidden = false

            // Get the difference between the map’s current direction and the user’s heading, then convert it from degrees to radians.
            let rotation: CGFloat = -MGLRadiansFromDegrees(mapView!.direction - heading)

            // If the difference would be perceptible, rotate the arrow.
            if abs(rotation) > 0.01 {
                // Disable implicit animations of this rotation, which reduces lag between changes.
                CATransaction.begin()
                CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
                arrow.setAffineTransform(CGAffineTransform.identity.rotated(by: rotation))
                CATransaction.commit()
            }
        } else {
            arrow.isHidden = true
        }
    }

    private func setupLayers() {
        // This dot forms the base of the annotation.
        if dot == nil {
            dot = CALayer()
            dot.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size, height: size)

            // Use CALayer’s corner radius to turn this layer into a circle.
            dot.cornerRadius = size / 2
            dot.backgroundColor = super.tintColor.cgColor
            dot.borderWidth = 4
            dot.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
            layer.addSublayer(dot)
        }

        // This arrow overlays the dot and is rotated with the user’s heading.
        if arrow == nil {
            arrow = CAShapeLayer()
            arrow.path = arrowPath()
            arrow.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size / 2, height: size / 2)
            arrow.position = CGPoint(x: dot.frame.midX, y: dot.frame.midY)
            arrow.fillColor = dot.borderColor
            layer.addSublayer(arrow)
        }
    }

    // Calculate the vector path for an arrow, for use in a shape layer.
    private func arrowPath() -> CGPath {
        let max: CGFloat = size / 2
        let pad: CGFloat = 3

        let top =    CGPoint(x: max * 0.5, y: 0)
        let left =   CGPoint(x: 0 + pad,   y: max - pad)
        let right =  CGPoint(x: max - pad, y: max - pad)
        let center = CGPoint(x: max * 0.5, y: max * 0.6)

        let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
        bezierPath.move(to: top)
        bezierPath.addLine(to: left)
        bezierPath.addLine(to: center)
        bezierPath.addLine(to: right)
        bezierPath.addLine(to: top)
        bezierPath.close()

        return bezierPath.cgPath
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT ***************************************EDIT

I copy/pasted your entire code into a fresh Mapbox project and ran it on the simulator. It compiled and showed the usual (small) blue dot at my simulated location. Pressing the button did nothing - no new annotation and no error message.

Looking at your code you can see that you have two methods sitting outside the `ViewController` class. They are just floating in no man's land. One of them is the delegate method:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, viewFor annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> MGLAnnotationView?
```

If you move this method back inside the `ViewController` class it will be called when needed and provide the custom look for the user location that you want, ie. the large blue dot.

The other method outside the class is:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, didSelect annotation: MGLAnnotation)
```

However, you have another version of this method inside the class already so you will probably want to combine the functionality of the two into the one *inside* the class then get rid of the external one.

The reason for the 'ambiguous' error message you were encountering is that you declare `mapView` inside `ViewDidLoad` so it isn't available inside any other methods inside that class. Instead, declare `mapView` outside the method along with your other class properties and just use it as normal inside `ViewDidLoad` like this:

```
var annotation = MGLPointAnnotation()
var pointAnnotations = [MGLPointAnnotation]()

var mapView: MGLMapView! // Declared here

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    mapView = MGLMapView(frame: view.bounds) // Instantiated here. (No `let`)
    mapView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    mapView.delegate = self
```

Now your button will drop a standard annotation at the user's location. You can just see it behind your big blue dot. If any of this is unclear let me know.

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer! the line "mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)" is the one that brings the error I cited in my original post (Type of expression is ambiguous without more context). It's being trigged in my function and yours as well. do you have an idea to fix that?

Comment: You have the line `let point = Annotation()` Can you show your code for the class Annotation?

Comment: This has already become obsolete. The class Annotation() was simply an MGLPointAnnotation()-class with an .id-member to link each entry to an UUID but I couldn't make that work...

Comment: The command "mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)" only works outside a function. As soon as I write it inside one, the error occurs...

Comment: You really shouldn't be able to write that statement outside of a function :) It sounds as if you may have accidentally put functions within functions or something like that. This might be the root cause of the error ambiguity. Are you able to pare down your code to be able to post the complete class while still retaining the error?

Comment: I've added the full code to the original question. In my opinion is the "mapView.addAnnotations(pointAnnotations)" command not inside a function...  but I just realized that you were right: When I thought that that command was outside a function, it was actually (by accident) in the "override func viewDidLoad()"

Comment: @TDog - please see the amended answer.

Comment: I can't thank you enough for your patient help and advice! The error isn't occurring anymore but now there's another one: when I press the button in the app, it crashes and it says: `Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil wile implicitly unwrapping an Optional value` in the line where I add the annotation to the mapView. I've already read and tried some things but without having any clue it's pretty hard to get behind that message... As far as I understand this matter, the problem might be the way `annotation` is declared (?)

Comment: Did you make sure that you have this line in `ViewDidLoad` ? `mapView = MGLMapView(frame: view.bounds)` it’s the same as you had previously but without the `let` since it is being declared outside the method.

Comment: Oh I didn't see that. Now it works and I get an annotation marker every time that I press the button! :D The location marker was flickering between the most recent annotation and the actual position, wich is moving due to low accuracy of GPS but I found the reason for that and eliminated it (a function that centered the view on the annotation..) Thanks again for your help! You are a great person and without you I probably would still be stuck and desperate.. THANK YOU!!!

Comment: Now I only need to make those annotations permanent, deletable and editable but that's another story  May I ask how it comes that you have so much knowledge about swift and programming?

Comment: Thanks and if my answer helped would you mind accepting it? I'm really just a hobbyist and self taught mostly from the web. Swift and iOS is a steep learning curve so I'd really recommend something like the free tutorials on https://www.raywenderlich.com. They'll show you how to structure your apps properly and once you have a solid framework you'll find things slot into place a lot easier.

Comment: Accepted ;) Thanks for the tip! It looks like a useful website. Thanks for all the help and I wish you all the best! Greetings from Germany :)